# Strange behavior when I try to close a searchview

Tags: java, android, android-studio, menu, searchbar

I created a toolbar with a search icon which launches a searchview on clic. However, I tried to add a `setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener`when user press back on his phone to close the searchview but the icon appears on the left and the back icon of the toolbar is always present.

[image]

---

This is the xml code of my toolbar:

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/topAppBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_menu"
            app:title="Notes" />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

with the menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView" />

</menu>
```

an my activity:

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        topAppBar = findViewById(R.id.topAppBar);
        setSupportActionBar(topAppBar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.top_app_bar, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        final SearchView searchView = (SearchView) item.getActionView();

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.search) {

            searchView.setOnQueryTextFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (!hasFocus) {
                        searchView.setIconified(true);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

---

PS: I have lots of issues with with this searchview, have yout got a better way to add search mechanism in a toolbar ?

Comment: IIRC, you want to use `searchView.setIconified(true)` instead of `searchView.onActionViewCollapsed()`.

Comment: Unfortunately, same behavior

Comment: Wait a second. What's the point of the `filterNotes()` method? The `SearchView` itself already handles expanding and collapsing appropriately.

Comment: hmm, no filterNotes() is used to filter a RecyclerView but I did not put this part and `searchView.setMaxWidth( Integer.MAX_VALUE);` is to expand the searchview in landscape mode because it doesn't take all the screen

Comment: Well, I don't see any `RecyclerView` or filtering in that method, but I guess my main point was, why do you have that method set as the `android:onClick` on that `<item>`? Why aren't you doing that setup in `onCreateOptionsMenu()` or `onPrepareOptionsMenu()`, instead of every time it's clicked?

Comment: I don't know the difference, in terms of optimization it's the same isn't it? instead of overriding the method `onCreateOptionsMenu()`, I call a function when we click on the search icon in the menu.

Comment: In general, if you can do something only once, it's preferable to do it like that, instead of repeatedly doing it continuously. Also, I just noticed that you're using the `app:menu` attribute, so you can do that setup in `onCreate()` (once), instead of overriding the options menu methods. I'm still not sure why you have the `OnFocusChangeListener`, though, since the `SearchView` will handle collapsing itself.

Comment: Beyond that, this is a pretty standard `SearchView` setup, aside from those things I mentioned, and I've never observed the described behavior. Those are the only two odd things out here, so if changing, or temporarily removing, those don't fix it, I'm thinking we might not have a [mcve] here.

Comment: I edit this topic with your tips but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

I fix the problem by adding:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (searchView != null && !searchView.isIconified())
            searchView.setIconified(true);
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```